# why does StrutsJunit4TestCase invoke the execute() method in a struts rest configured web application?

Tags: rest, junit, execute, nosuchmethod

I recently write a web application with Struts2 REST, and I ran the junit test for a Action class then I got an error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cn.fshk.stock.struts.biz.admin.AuthorizationController.execute()

But it seems to run correctly in Tomcat.

Dose it suppose to invoke the index() method in a Struts2 REST controller?

Can anyone give me some help?

- here is the struts.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      ...        
  <struts>

    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="rest,struts,struts2,action,actions" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="cn.fshk.stock.struts" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="action,do,,xhtml,xml,json" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionMapper" />

  </struts>
  ```
- The struts.properties:

  ```
  struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8
  struts.objectFactory = spring
  struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire = name
  struts.objectFactory.spring.useClassCache = true
  struts.multipart.parser=jakarta
  struts.multipart.saveDir=
  struts.multipart.maxSize=2097152
  struts.serve.static=true
  struts.serve.static.browserCache=true
  struts.tag.altSyntax=true
  struts.devMode = true
  struts.i18n.reload=false
  struts.ui.theme=xhtml
  struts.ui.templateDir=template
  struts.ui.templateSuffix=ftl
  struts.configuration.xml.reload=false
  struts.url.http.port = 80
  struts.url.https.port = 443
  struts.custom.i18n.resources=globalmessages
  struts.dispatcher.parametersWorkaround = false
  struts.freemarker.wrapper.altMap=true
  struts.xslt.nocache=false
  ```
- The TestCase Class

  ```
  package cn.fshk.stock2.struts;
        ...
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:application*.xml" })
  @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
  public class TestStrutsBase<ActionName> extends StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase<ActionName> {

      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("cn.fshk");

      @Test
      public void testStrutsUtil() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ServletException {

          String result = executeAction("/biz/admin/authorization");            
          logger.debug(result);
       }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I find out what's wrong.

I need to add

```
    request.setMethod("GET");
```

before

```
    excuteAction("...");
```

Comment: I just tried writing a struts2 test case, but I was unable to use assertNotNull etc. functions. Please let me know how to proceed further.